# Unknown Column in "field list"

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Here's my code. I want to create a table with two variables have same values for every 100000 row:

```
var_list = ["IMU_sample_rate","grf_sample_rate"]
cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tableName} ({', '.join(field + ' FLOAT(53)' for field in var_list)});")

for i in range(100000):
    IMU_sample_rate = 500
    grf_sample_rate = 100

    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({', '.join(field for field in var_list)}) VALUES ({IMU_sample_rate},{grf_sample_rate});")
```

why there's pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'IMU_sample_rate' in 'field list'") here?

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute(query, args)` takes an argument list with the values,  which are then quoted and replaced in the original query. This is to help protect people against SQL injection.

Comment: thank you for your comment! Could you please clarify which part went wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the actual DB schema? Or maybe use DROP TABLE IF EXISTS before, so it gets re-created.